# PowerShell - Information After Each Input

Tags: function, powershell, wildcard, feedback

I was wondering if it's possible to receive information after each input (each line) in PowerShell.
I would like to use it afterwards for some custom functions.
If you don't think it's possible, perhaps it would be possible to create custom functions with asterisk (wild card)? E.g. type in computer's name (which always begins the same way) and receive ping to this computer as feedback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a sample code where in you would like to receive information after each input?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh Anything to be honest. I would like it to be universal if possible. Perhaps there's some variable in PS which is the same for every input? I guess it should work like some event handler.